# printf("%s",stringName) prints the wrong text but only once

Tags: arduino

I have a menu function, in which I input a question and two options, then the user choses one. It works just fine everytime but one ; I call

```
 if (menu("ou est le corps?","interieur ","exterieur")==1)
    {
```

but instead of printing "interieur " It shows "p?"
it works just fine without the space, but I need to make a space and \n does quite the same thing.
I have another call of this function, with \n which works fine so I have no idea about why this wouldn't work. Anyone has got an idea?

PS : the value of choix1 is then sent via bluetooth, and there it stays intact.

PPS : tell me if something is unclear, I'm not naturally english

PPPS(sorry) : tried to run the same code again, it seems to print a random character followed by "?", I had twice "p?", once "?" and once " '?"

[updates] once "#?"

```
int menu (String texte, String choix1, String choix2)
{
  envoye = 0;

  rxValue = "0";
  while (digitalRead(M5_BUTTON_HOME) != LOW && rxValue == "0")
  {


    heure();
    M5.Lcd.setTextSize(2);
    M5.Lcd.print(texte);
    M5.Lcd.printf("\n");

    if (selec == 0)
    {
      M5.Lcd.printf("->%s   %s", choix1, choix2);
    }
    else
    {
      M5.Lcd.printf("  %s ->%s", choix1, choix2);
    }
    if (M5.BtnB.read() != 0)
    {
      if (selec == 0)
      {
        selec = 1;
      }
      else
      {
        selec = 0;
      }
      while (M5.BtnB.read() != 0) 
      {
      if(digitalRead(M5_BUTTON_HOME) == LOW)
      {
        M5.Lcd.fillScreen(BLACK);
        delay(1000);
        if(digitalRead(M5_BUTTON_HOME) == LOW)
      {
        choix=50;
        heure();
        delay(1000);
        return 1;
      }
      }
        }

    }

    if (deviceConnected && envoye == 0)
    {

      sendchoix(texte, choix1, choix2);
      envoye++;

    }
  }
  if (rxValue != "0")
  {

    recuble = &rxValue[0];
    selec = atoi(recuble) - 1;


    rxValue = "0";
  }
  M5.Lcd.fillScreen(BLACK);
  delay(300);
  return selec;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
int menu (String texte, String choix1, String choix2) {
[...]
      M5.Lcd.printf("->%s   %s", choix1, choix2);
```

You cannot treat `String` objects as `const char*`, which is what the format specifier `%s` is expecting. `String` is an Arduino class for storing.. strings/character data, but an object of this class is not equivalent to the raw pointer to the data.

For that, you need to call the `c_str()` method on the `String` object to get the C-String pointer to the data, as shown in the documentation [1].

```cpp
[..]
      M5.Lcd.printf("->%s   %s", choix1.c_str(), choix2.c_str());
[..]
```

[1] https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/c_str/